# Notation problem: How can I reduce the homogeneous polynomial in the simple way?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, polynomials, notation

I would like to express all of the complex polynomials including
$z^3, \overline{z}^3, |z|^2 z, |z|^2 \overline{z}, |z| z^2, |z|\overline{z}^2, |z|^3$ and their linear combinations in one simple notation or a sentence. Would you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

$$f(r,\varphi)=r^3T(e^{i\varphi}),$$
where $T$ is a [complex trigonometric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_polynomial)  of degree 3, $$T(e^{i\varphi})=\sum_{k=-n}^{k=n}a_ke^{ik\varphi}$$